# What does it mean to make window global - isn't it global already?

Tags: reactjs, window, global

I'm learning about [testing](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) React but don't get how the below makes sense since window is already globally available everywhere isn't it?

> You will need to have window, window.document and
>   window.document.createElement globally available before you import
>   React. Otherwise React will think it can't access the DOM and methods
>   like setState won't work.

Comment: Remember that JavaScript and the DOM are different things and JavaScript can run in an environment where there is no DOM. This is just describing how `renderIntoDocument` determines if DOM is available: check if there's a global `window.document.createElement`. If you're running in the browser you will obviously have that.

Comment: How else might you run this besides the browser?

Comment: NodeJS would be the common example.